# Should I repair or replace a dryer heating element and housing connector?

Tags: repair, dryer

I have a Samsung dryer that has a burnt out heating element.  I purchased a new one and removed the old one from the dryer.  I have no problem with any of this.

My problem is that the element connectors go through the housing and connect to wires through a ceramic piece as shown here:

[image]

I broke this piece by accident and I can't purchase this by itself.

1. Is it safe to super glue it and wrap electrical tape around it?
2. What purpose does it serve?  I am thinking that it keeps the wires from touching the housing.

The housing (the image) that contains that piece runs from $65 to $100.  I don't need the whole thing but I will purchase if that is my only option.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you have a picture of the actual damage? Ceramics are used because nothing else will stand the heat which means that glue or tape will turn to smoke. And yes it is an insulator which means that it keeps bad things from happening, you do not want anything arcing to ground if it fails.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  Unfortunately I made the mistake of not paying attention to how the previous connectors were supposed to be removed.  I tried to force it and the ends broke off from each hole/slot.  It sounds like for safety I need to just purchase the whole assembly as shown.  I thought as much but wanted to ask before I did.  Thanks again.

Comment: @FiascoLabs That sounds like an answer to me.  Please consider converting your comment to an answer.

Comment: @FiascoLabs I agree about making the comment an answer so that I can mark it as such.  I went out this morning and found an old appliance shop that had the ceramic piece from an broken element that he gave to me.  All is well now.

Comment: Converted to an answer as requested. Sounds like you still have an appliance repair shop like Mr. Rhoder had here till he retired. The good part was the sorted used parts that could be used to resurrect just about any appliance that had been relatively popular. Sadly, those days have passed and you end up rebuying really expensive looking and costly appliances that have little longevity, requiring replacement any time you must make more than the most minor repairs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have a picture of the actual damage?

Ceramics are used because nothing else will stand the heat which means that glue or tape will turn to smoke.

And yes it is an insulator which means that it keeps bad things from happening, you do not want anything arcing to ground if it fails.